# SwiftUI TextField wobble on text change. Doesn't reproduce on all machine

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

So I made a simple app with simple text field instance bound to a local variable in SwiftUI

```
TextField("Main task", text: $store.mainTask)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Display", size: 14))
```

The text field is wrapped inside a view with transition and animation.

```
// text field is inside custom View
// conditional rendering—if that matters
if (true) {
  CustomView()
    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(0.5)), removal: AnyTransition.opacity.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.1))))
}
```

I distributed the beta. Some people say they experienced the text wobbling as they typed. Some didn't. Does anyone know what's the reason?

I think it might be related with the animation, but I'm not so sure.

[image]

Comment: What else is performed in code on text input? Any side effects? Observers? Refresh? It does not look as it is TextField itself problem. Would you show more code?

Comment: Hello @Asperi, sorry for the late reply. There's nothing else performed with the text input. There's an observable object that changes every time timer ticks. It shouldn't be the problem though as timer haven't started yet.

Comment: Also, I updated the description for more detail (as per your request). Thanks!